# Iso-Area jumping over parts without streets (QGIS QNEAT3 Plugin)

Tags: qgis-3, isochrone

I am using the QGIS Plugin 'QNEAT3' (version 1.0.4) to calculate Iso-Areas. They are only relevant for me in one country, so I only have this country's street network. But the Iso-Areas are jumping over the parts without streets outside the country and then continue in another part of the country.
To show what I mean I provided a map with my result.
How can I prevent this and make the Iso-Areas stop at the border of the country?

[image: Map with Iso-Area result]

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs due to a problem with the QgsTinInterpolator and cannot be changed at the moment. I found the answer on: https://github.com/root676/QNEAT3/issues/6